# How do I link to a Facebook user in the iOS App by using the username?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to link to a specific profile page in the Facebook iOS app by using the (semi-official) URL scheme.

`fb://profile/123456789` works fine, but `fb://profile/someusername` does not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This URL works for me: `fb://profile?id=<id>` where `<id>` is either the numeric ID or the username.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether facebook intends to keep this sort of thing constant, but here is the code that I use in my project. The FB link works on my iPhone (iOS 5) with one of the newer versions of the FB app.

Note that you need the numeric page ID to get the FB app link. This method worked for me: http://inlinevision.com/apps/how-to-find-your-facebook-page-id/

```
NSURL* direct = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/NUMERIC_PAGE_ID"];
NSURL* web = [NSURL URLWithString:@"REGULAR_OLD_WEB_LINK"];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:direct]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:direct];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:web];
}
```